# Sort results without using order by clause

Tags: php

I attended an interview, at there the interviewer asked me a question that how can we sort the MySQL result without using ORDER BY clause in PHP?
Is possible?
If the answer is yes then how?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to load the values into an array in PHP and then use some sorting algorithm in PHP to sort the array. This sometimes lets you use more complicated sorting algorithms than the MySQL offers you.

Comment: thank you, but it is possible to toggle that sorted result in ascending or descending when we click on link ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch the result [as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) first.

Comment: `as an array` is not needed at all.